# Dynamics CRM Metadata not refreshing in Tibco Scribe

Tags: dynamics-crm

I created a new custom entity, but it is not showing up in entity list of lookup block.

Connection is created successfully, but the latest customization are not pulled I guess. I waited for a day though.

What should I do to see a new custom entity in the list from lookup block of Maps?

[image]

Comment: I think you already know this, but for the connection on setting gear you can reset metadata, clicking it shall refresh your metadata. I remember small changes with scribe did not reflected metadata. Doing Reset Metadata did helped.

Comment: @AnkUser That was it, I did remember I tried that but not sure at what point of time in which instance I "Reset metadata". pls post it as answer

Comment: Thanks, just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Tibco (Scribe) when you connect Dynamics crm enviornemnt, under Connection, there is small gear (settings) setting gear you can reset metadata, clicking it shall refresh your metadata.

Please see below Image for Refrence.

[image]